# WPF Adding StatusBarItem using mvvm and Datatemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dynamic, datatemplate, statusbaritem

I'm trying to add `StatusBarItem` dynamically by using mvvm pattern but i don't know what to do.

If i write the code that i want to create in XAML file, it looks like this:

```
<StatusBar Grid.Row="2" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StatusBarItem Content="There's a sentence in it."/>
    </StatusBarItem>
                
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StatusBarItem Content="Status 1" Background="Yellow" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
            <StatusBarItem Content="Status 2" Background="Red" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

But I want to dynamically add 'StatusBarItem' on the right side.
Because i can see the status of the programs that are communicating with WPF program, and it can be multiple.
(On the left, there's only a sentence. And `StatusBarItem` which shows the status of the program communicating will be added from the right.)

So i write the code like this.

**StatusBarVieModel class**

```
public class StatusBarViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _alignment;
    public string Alignment
    {
        get
        {
            return _alignment;
        }
        set
        {
            _alignment = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Alignment));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<BarItemViewModel> _barItems;
    public ObservableCollection<BarItemViewModel> BarItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _barItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _barItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BarItems));
        }
    }
}
```

**BarItemViewModel class**

```
public class BarItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _itemName;
    public string ItemName
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemName;
        }
        set
        {
            _itemName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemName));
        }
    }

    private string _backgroundColor;
    public string BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _backgroundColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _backgroundColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundColor));
        }
    }

    private string _foregroundColor;
    public string ForegroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _foregroundColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _foregroundColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ForegroundColor));
        }
    }
```

**MainWindowView.xaml**

```
...
<StatusBar Grid.Row="2" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding StatusBars}" >
    <StatusBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:BarItemViewModel}">
            <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Alignment}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding BarItems.ItemName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StatusBar.ItemTemplate>
</StatusBar>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel() 
    {
        CreateBarItems();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<StatusBarViewModel> _statusBars;
    public ObservableCollection<StatusBarViewModel> StatusBars
    {
        get
        {
            return this._statusBars;
        }

        set
        {
            this._statusBars = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StatusBars");
        }
    }

    private void CreateBarItems()
    {
        StatusBars = new ObservableCollection<StatusBarViewModel>
        {
            new StatusBarViewModel
            {
                Alignment = "Left",
                BarItems = new ObservableCollection<BarItemViewModel>
                {
                    new BarItemViewModel{ ItemName = "test1", BackgroundColor = "Black", ForegroundColor = "White"},
                }
            },
            new StatusBarViewModel
            {
                Alignment = "Right",
                BarItems = new ObservableCollection<BarItemViewModel>
                {
                    new BarItemViewModel{ ItemName = "test2", BackgroundColor = "#52d976", ForegroundColor = "Black"},
                    new BarItemViewModel{ ItemName = "test3", BackgroundColor = "Red", ForegroundColor = "Black"},
                }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

But if i run this code, it gives me binding error with `BarItems.ItemName`...
How can I add a `StatusBarItem` dynamically as I want?

Comment: StatusBar is a ItemsControl. Please refer to [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to learn how to define aDataTemplate properly. Additionally, in MVVM you don't handle UI in the view model. Layout handling, for example element alignment in the GUI or styling in general belongs to the view alone. You usually define a Style/DataTemplate to handle this. ItemsControl also accepts a StyleSelector/DataTemplateSelector to allow selecting from multiple Style/DataTemplate resources dynamically.

Comment: @BionicCode I'll find a way to use the StyleSelector/DataTemplateSelector. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use an ItemsControl to create multiple elements from BarItems collection:

```
<StatusBar Grid.Row="2" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding StatusBars}" >
    <StatusBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:StatusBarViewModel}">
            <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Alignment}">

             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BarItems}">
               <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:BarItemViewModel}">
                         <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             </ItemsControl>

            </StatusBarItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StatusBar.ItemTemplate>
</StatusBar>
```

also note that you had a wrong DataType on the first DataTemplate

Comment: Why do you add a StatusBarItem to the template that is applied to a StatusBarItem? StatusBarItem is the item container for the StatusBar control.

Comment: Alignment is not working, but I will find a way. Thank you.